# Alternative to RDB$GET_CONTEXT and RDB$SET_CONTEXT

Tags: sql, firebird, interbase

I need to convert SQL statements [`RDB$GET_CONTEXT`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-intfunc-get_context.html) and [`RDB$SET_CONTEXT`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-intfunc-set_context.html) from Firebird to Interbase so what I should use ?

Here is the complete Firebird SQL:

```
if (rdb$get_context('USER_TRANSACTION', 'Lock_Trigger') = '1') then exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

These functions are more or less* shortcuts for accessing Firebird's key-value system table. You can imitate it with Global Temporary Tables

> Use global temporary tables to allow an application to pass
>   intermediate result sets  from one section of an application to
>   another section of the same application.
>
> Creating a Global Temporary Table
>
> A global temporary table is declared to a database schema via
>   the normal
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE statement with the following syntax:
> CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE table (<col_def> [, <col_def> | 
> <tconstraint> ...])
> [ON COMMIT {PRESERVE | DELETE} ROWS];
> ```
>
> The first argument that you supply CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE is
>   the  temporary table name, which is required and must be unique among
>   all table and  procedure names in the database. You must also supply
>   at least one column  definition.
>
> The ON COMMIT clause describes
>   whether the rows of the temporary table are  deleted on each
>   transaction commit (ON COMMIT DELETE) or are left in place  (ON COMMIT
>   PRESERVE) to be used by other transactions in the same database 
>   attachment. If the ON COMMIT is not specified then the default
>   behavior is to  DELETE ROWS on transaction commit.

`ON COMMIT DELETE` GTT imitates `*context('USER_TRANSACTION'...)` while `ON COMMIT PRESERVE` imitates `*context('USER_SESSION'...)`. Refer to Interbase DataDef manual for details.

So you can create GTT with fields (KEY, VALUE) and simply insert/update/select the values you need:

```
Get:
select Value from MY_GTT where Key = :key

Set:
select count(*) from MY_GTT where Key = :key into :Cnt;
if (:Cnt = 0) then
   insert into MY_GTT(Key, Value) values(:Key, :Value)
else
   update MY_GTT SET Value=:Value where Key = :key
```

Note that collisions are possible with `COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` GTT's when reading/writing the same value from multiple transactions of the same attachment.

---

*I believe these functions also provide atomic type of operations to avoid read-write collisions.

Comment: Can you provide a working translation of the OP's original query?  For example, it seems to me that you'll need to add a third column to the GTT for context or, in this specific case, make the GTT ON COMMIT DELETE to simulate the OP's context of `USER_TRANSACTION`.

Comment: @pilcrow yes, GTT needs to be declared with `ON COMMIT DELETE` to imitate `*context('USER_TRANSACTION'...)` and with `ON COMMIT PRESERVE` to imitate `*context('USER_SESSION'...)`. `*context('SYSTEM'...)` behavior couldn't be implemented with GTT